# Fastest way to capture image from a HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, html5-canvas, html5-video

Here's my code to capture an image from a Canvas playing video:

```
    let drawImage = function(time) {
        prevCtx.drawImage(videoPlayer, 0, 0, w, h);
        requestAnimationFrame(drawImage);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(drawImage);

    let currIndex = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
        if(currIndex === 30) {
            currIndex = 0;
            console.log("Finishing video...");
            videoWorker.postMessage({action : "finish"});
        } else {
            console.log("Adding frame...");
            // w/o this `toDataURL` this loop runs at 30 cycle / second
            // so that means, this is the hot-spot and needs optimization:
            const base64img = preview.toDataURL(mimeType, 0.9);
            videoWorker.postMessage({ action: "addFrame", data: base64img});
            currIndex++;
        }
    }, 1000 / 30)
```

The goal is at each 30 frames (which should be at 1 second) it would trigger to *transcode* the frames added.

The problem here is that the `preview.toDataURL(mimeType, 0.9);` adds at least 1 second, without it the log shows the `currIndex === 30` gets triggered every second. What would be the best approach to be able to capture at least about 30 FPS image. **What is the fastest way to capture image from a HTML Canvas** that it will not be the bottleneck of real-time video transcoding process?

Comment: What about [`.toBlob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) ? [`.captureStream()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/captureStream) looks promising too ...

Answer (score 6):

You should probably revise your project, because saving the whole video as still images will blow out the memory of most devices in no time. Instead have a look at [MediaStreams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream/MediaStream) and [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/mediarecorder) APIs, which are able to do the transcoding and compression in real time. You can request a MediaStream from a canvas through its [`captureStream()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/captureStream) method.

---

The fastest is probably to send an [ImageBitmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmap) to your Worker thread, these are really fast to generate from a canvas (simple copy of the pixel buffer), and can be *transferred* to your worker script, from where you should be able to draw it on a an OffscreenCanvas.

Main drawback: it's currently only supported in latest Chrome and Firefox (through webgl), and this can't be polyfilled...

*main.js*

```
else {
  console.log("Adding frame...");
  const bitmap = await createImageBitmap(preview);
  videoWorker.postMessage({ action: "addFrame", data: bitmap }, [bitmap]);
  currIndex++;
}
```

*worker.js*

```
const canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(width,height);
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); // Chrome only
onmessage = async (evt) => {
  // ...
  ctx.drawImage( evt.data.data, 0, 0 );
  const image = await canvas.convertToBlob();
  storeImage(image);
};
```

---

An other option is to transfer an [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) data. Not as fast as an ImageBitmap, it still has the advantage of not stopping your main thread with the compression part and since it can be transferred, the message to the Worker isn't computation heavy either.
If you go this road, you may want to compress the data using something like [pako](https://nodeca.github.io/pako/) (which uses the compression algorithm used by PNG images) from your Worker thread.

*main.js*

```
else {
  console.log("Adding frame...");
  const img_data = prevCtx.getImageData(0,0,width,height);
  videoWorker.postMessage({ action: "addFrame", data: img_data }, [img_data.data]);
  currIndex++;
}
```

*worker.js*

```
onmessage = (evt) => {
 // ...
 const image = pako.deflate(evt.data.data); // compress to store
 storeImage(image);
};
```

Comment: The problem I had with `MedaiRecorder` is that it can't be used for live streaming. I mean if I use it, start of recording is delayed, and after recording you have to stop it and it will encode somehow which is slow also, thus, it can't be used to generate 1 second video chunks. For example I need to generate every second a 1 second video (AVI or MP4 whatever codec is available...) I can't do that when I use `MediaRecorded`

Comment: Why do you need a one second video? Not sure many players can play that small videos anyway.

Comment: Why does it need to be full video files? Can't you just send chunks of it? Or even better, send just the MediaStream over WebRTC.

Comment: To better describe what I am trying to achieve open this https://www.techsmith.com/blog/instructional-videos/ and play a video while checking the developer tools for network inspection, there are TS video files being sent over the network that are segments of the complete video. That's for a recorded video from a streaming server, in my case however, the TS files would be coming from the client browser webcam streamed to other clients in similar fashion.

Comment: Also I cannot uses WebRTC at this stage of my project, for this stage need to make sure it works first with WebSockets. I have tested Websockets and was able to do real-time video frame-by-frame (JPEG streaming) the problem is it eats up bandwidth so need to encode first.

Comment: ;-) But you need WebRTC, it's like saying I want to build a 100 floors building but I don't want to use cranes, only a hammer. Simply setup a WebRTC server, use something like [janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/) to broadcast the stream to multiple clients

Comment: Also it seems its not possible to use OffscreenCanvas in Web worker: `videoWorker.js:532 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'
    at onmessage (videoWorker.js:532)`

Comment: The error message says that whatever you passed to `drawImage` as first argument was not  an ImageBitmap.